# Find element by value in array and unset element

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have a next array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [45] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1 day
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [45] => Array
                (
                    [0] => - None -
                )

        )

)
```

I need to find an element by value '- None -' and unset fully the next element:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [45] => Array
                (
                    [0] => - None -
                )

        )
```

Does any ideas, guys?

Comment: Can the value `None` only appear in array at the deepest level?

Comment: Just find it by iteration and unset `$i + 1`. I see no recursion here.

Comment: @Breus it's the default structure. Only this case.

Comment: @JustName WHat do you mean by unset next element? Also, you can you show the var_export() of your array in your post?

Comment: _“Does any ideas, guys?”_ - the general idea would be that you go read up on some basics, so that you can then make an _attempt_ on your own. _“and unset fully the next element”_ - and by “next”, you appear to actually mean “previous” here …?

Comment: @vivek_23 I showed my var_export() array in post at the first frame. In the second frame, this one needs to be removed by value.

Comment: @JustName It's not var_export(). It's print_r() that you showed. Anyway, so you want the second frame to be removed from the original first frame? If yes, then what do you mean by _unset next element_?

Comment: @04FS by "next" I mean in the frame below

Comment: @vivek_23 Frame below. "Unset" like a remove.

Comment: What “frames” are you talking about? You have an array structure here, that has items, or elements - not “frames”. And even if that is what you actually meant - there is no _next_ one after the one with the `- None -` element.

Comment: @04FS One more time. By "frame", I meant the array structure, but "frame" I shortly named "array structure", yes I see it will be not obviously moment. And by "next element" I meant not the next element after "- None -", but the next array structure or element of array structure kind of pointer of that. Is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use next `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($ar as $key=>$row){
    foreach($row as $ind=>$val){
        if ($val[0] == '- None -') unset($ar[$key]);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nlC3W)

It will check the lowest level value and [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)s the row if it's `true`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a simple recursion strategy to deeply remove the `- None -` values and return either `true` or `false` to parent level looping.

If we receive a `true` from our child level, we `unset()` the current index in the current level array. If we receive a `false`, everything moves as normal.

```
<?php

function removeNoneElements(&$arr){
    $temp = $arr;
    $hasNone = false;
    foreach($temp as $index => $val){
        if(is_array($val)){
            $containsNone = removeNoneElements($val);
            if($containsNone){
                $hasNone = true;
                unset($arr[$index]);
            }
        }else if($val === '- None -'){
            unset($arr[$index]);
            $hasNone = true;
        }
    }

    return $hasNone;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/N3AP3

Comment: It's a working solution, but the solution by Aksen P is also working but short.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (I made this on a single array cause I don't know what really is your logic).

```
$found = false;
foreach($elems as $elem){
    if($found){
        unset($elem);
        $found = false;
    }
    $found = ($elem == " - None");   
}
```

Comment: This is a strange solution. $found not available in the condition and $elem after the condition is also not available.

Comment: What do you mean ? You have a scope issue ? $found is known in the whole scope and $elem is known in the foreach so I don't see what is bothering you.
You just store in $found the value of the previous iteration.

Comment: @Minirock `" - None"` can be more levels deep. Not necessarily on the first level.

Comment: Well the question isn't really clear about this, and it's just adding a loop level on top of it. The idea  behind this answer is just to show how to remember what previous element was in order to know if you need to delete or not. We also don't know if he want to delete the next element in the current array or on the top level array.